android trout in cvd cannot start graphics
When trying to run default CVD configuration with arm64 trout image on x86 i cannot get graphics to work. I am able to connect to vm via adb, but webRTC interface doesn't work. Logcat mentions this:
05-07 07:39:16.429  7727  7765 I EGL_emulation: Opening libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
05-07 07:39:16.432  7727  7765 I EGL_emulation: Opening libGLESv2_emulation.so
05-07 07:39:16.438  7727  7765 E surfaceflinger: open_verbose_path:56: Could not open '/dev/goldfish_pipe_dprctd': No such file or directory
05-07 07:39:16.438  7727  7765 E surfaceflinger: open_verbose:128: both vsock and goldfish_pipe paths failed
05-07 07:39:16.438  7727  7765 E surfaceflinger: connect: failed to connect to opengles pipe
05-07 07:39:16.438  7727  7765 E surfaceflinger: pipe error: fd -2 errno 2
05-07 07:39:16.439  7727  7765 E HostConnection: Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)
05-07 07:39:16.439  7727  7765 E EGL_emulation: Failed to establish connection with the host
05-07 07:39:16.439  7727  7765 W libEGL  : eglInitialize(0x73c5338030) failed (EGL_SUCCESS)
05-07 07:39:16.440  7727  7765 E EGL_emulation: tid 7765: eglGetConfigs(1167): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
05-07 07:39:16.440  7727  7765 E EGL_emulation: tid 7765: eglChooseConfig(1189): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
05-07 07:39:16.440  7727  7765 E EGL_emulation: tid 7765: eglGetConfigs(1167): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
05-07 07:39:16.441  7727  7765 E EGL_emulation: tid 7765: eglChooseConfig(1189): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
05-07 07:39:16.441  7727  7765 W RenderEngine: no suitable EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query
05-07 07:39:16.441  7727  7765 E EGL_emulation: tid 7765: eglGetConfigs(1167): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
05-07 07:39:16.442  7727  7765 E EGL_emulation: tid 7765: eglChooseConfig(1189): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
05-07 07:39:16.442  7727  7765 F RenderEngine: no suitable EGLConfig found, giving up
05-07 07:39:16.445  7727  7765 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 7765 (surfaceflinger), pid 7727 (surfaceflinger)
05-07 07:39:16.668  7726  7726 I netd    : Creating child chains: 1861724us
05-07 07:39:16.672  7726  7726 I netd    : Setting up OEM hooks: 4788us
05-07 07:39:16.678  7721  7721 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit uid 0 <<<<<<
05-07 07:39:16.680  7721  7721 I boot_progress_start: 562779
05-07 07:39:16.724   338   346 W ServiceManagerCppClient: Waited one second for SurfaceFlingerAIDL (is service started? Number of threads started in the threadpool: 3. Are binder threads started and available?)
05-07 07:39:16.726  7726  7726 I netd    : Setting up FirewallController hooks: 53491us
05-07 07:39:16.750   319  7779 W libc    : Unable to set property "ctl.interface_start" to "aidl/SurfaceFlingerAIDL": error code: 0x20
05-07 07:39:16.796  7726  7726 I netd    : Setting up TetherController hooks: 70108us
05-07 07:39:16.842  7726  7726 I netd    : Setting up BandwidthController hooks: 46396us
05-07 07:39:16.843  7726  7726 I netd    : Setting up IdletimerController hooks: 655us

and kernel this:
[   20.400783][  T319] servicemanager: Caller(pid=338,uid=1003,sid=u:r:automotive_display_service:s0) Since 'SurfaceFlingerAIDL' could not be found trying to start it as a lazy AIDL service. (if it's not configured to be a lazy service, it may be stuck starting or still starting).
[   20.413751][    T1] init: Control message: Could not find 'aidl/SurfaceFlingerAIDL' for ctl.interface_start from pid: 319 (/system/bin/servicemanager)

So far i have tried x86 image which works as it should. I assigned more memory and CPUs but it doesn't change anything. I can only try guest_swiftshader gpu mode as my machine does not have any external gpu.
